# parsing strange kind of JSON

Tags: android, json

I'm using Android, and I have a strange question: how can I parse JSON data that has the following format:

```
"2"
```

The JSON URL result is this number only, without any brackets (`{ }` or `[ ]`). How this array is formed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's JSON? What does the Content-Type header have in it?

Comment: The problem, actually, it's not really that. I have to read this result in a String, but I need for a login, and it can be: "2" or "WRONG_PASS" or "WRONG_USER"

Comment: Then just treat the response as text/plain and build an if-then-elseif-else statement. If the string does start with a curly brace, then parse it as JSON.

Comment: @kwo: how? can you post a sample code please?

Comment: ok ok I solved my issue: simply, It was not JSON but only a String ! :) thank u for help to everybody :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First retrieve the remote URL and decide if it is JSON or text/plain

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/humans.txt");
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
int status = http.getResponseCode();
String contentType = http.getContentType();
String encoding = http.getContentEncoding() == null ? "utf-8" : http.getContentEncoding();
```

Read out the response body.

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int len = 0;
byte[] buffer = new buffer[1024];
while (len = (in.read(buffer)) {
  out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
String contents = new String(out.toByteArray(), encoding);
```

Based on the content type header you can decide if it is JSON or a plain/text contents. Alternatively, peek at the first character to see if it is an opening curly brace.

```
if (contentType == null) {
    // handle bad doc here
} else if (contentType.equals("application/json") || content.startsWith("{")) {
    // parse JSON document here
} else if (content.equals("2")) {
    // handle 2
} else if (content.equals("WRONG_PASS") || content.equals("WRONG_USER")) {
    // handle wrong user/pass
} else {
  // handle this as well
}
```

Comment: ok ok I solved my issue: simply, It was not JSON but only a String ! :) thank u for help to everybody :)

Answer (score 1):

That is not an array. It's not very clear from your question whether the quotation marks are included in the JSON or not. <strike>If yes, it's a valid JSON string. If not, it's a valid JSON number.</strike> Depending on the case, parsing it is very easy (using Android's built-in `org.json` parser):

```
String jsonString = (String) new JSONTokener("\"2\"").nextValue();
```

or:

```
int jsonInt = (Integer) new JSONTokener("2").nextValue();
```

---

**Edit:** to satisfy your scenario:

```
String jsonString = (String) new JSONTokener(someStringThatComesFromTheServer).nextValue();
if (jsonString.equals("WRONG_PASS")) {
  // do stuff
}
else if (jsonString.equals("WRONG_USER")) {
  // do stuff
}
else {
  // do stuff, such as:
  int userId = Integer.parseInt(jsonString);
}
```

---

**Edit 2:** I actually got in touch with Douglas Crockford, the author of RFC4627. It seems that:

> Formally, no, but it is sometimes useful.

So yes, the others were right, it's not RFC-valid JSON. Sorry for confusing people. However, it seems that most parsers understand it.

Comment: The problem, actually, it's not really that.
I have to read this result in a String, but I need for a login, and it can be: "2" or "WRONG_PASS" or "WRONG_USER"

Comment: your example it's very clear but I can't try it because I have the result from URL already in a JSONObject. What can I put as argument of JSONTokener ( instead of someStringThatComesFromTheServer)?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid JSON string. So you can't really parse it as JSON.

Comment: Please refer to JSON documentation @ http://www.json.org/.  This Felix is right- in either scenario, string or number, this would be valid JSON.

Comment: @Felix: No, JSON data either represents an object or an array: http://www.json.org/ You can also try it out at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I don't see where it says that the top-level element must be either an Object or an Array on json.org. And jsonlint is either broken or too much like jslint: providing recommendations, not syntax correction.

Comment: The problem, actually, it's not really that. I have to read this result in a String, but I need for a login, and it can be: "2" or "WRONG_PASS" or "WRONG_USER"

Comment: @Felix: RFC 4627 says a JSON text can be only an object or an array.

Comment: @JeremyP that section of the RFC is very unclear. It also states that "A JSON text is a sequence of tokens. The set of tokens includes six structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal names." which would suggest that it can also be a string or a number. On top of that, strings and numbers are objects as well.

Comment: @Felix: I find it very clear: "A JSON text is a serialized object or array". Strings and numbers are not objects: "An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).".

Comment: This is more of a comment!! :-P

Comment: ok ok I solved my issue: simply, It was not JSON but only a String ! :) thank u for help to everybody :)

Comment: @Felix: Section 4 defines a JSON parser like this "A JSON parser transforms a JSON text into another representation."  That's pretty clear.

Comment: @Felix:  And a JSON text is defined as an object or an array, look at the EBNF in section 2.

Answer (score -1):

That is not valid JSON, so you can't parse it as that.

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) says:

```
Parse error on line 1:
"2"
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

You can create valid JSON from it, either by putting it in an array:

```
["2"]
```

or in an object:

```
{"value":"2"}
```

Comment: The problem, actually, it's not really that. I have to read this result in a String, but I need for a login, and it can be: "2" or "WRONG_PASS" or "WRONG_USER"

Comment: @PiNuZ: All those are valid string values in JSON, but it's not valid JSON by itself. You can either wrap it in brackets to make it valid JSON, or you can parse it as something different than JSON.

Comment: JSONLint, just like JSLint, provides syntax recommendations, not validation. I have tried parsing `"2"` in Java's `org.json`, Chrome's native JSON parser (try `JSON.parse("\"2\"");` in the console) and Firefox's native JSON parser (just like in Chrome) and **it works**.

Comment: I have this as a JSONObject from URL. I just want to convert into a string but my app chrashes... I DOn't understand why

Comment: @Felix: Just because some libraries accept invalid JSON doesn't make it valid. Read the specification.

Comment: @PiNuZ: The reason why is simply because it's not valid JSON, so when you try to parse it as JSON you get an error. You have to request the data as plain text, and then parse it yourself.

Comment: @Guffa no, he will not get an error, as `org.json` considers it valid.

Comment: ok ok I solved my issue: simply, It was not JSON but only a String ! :) thank u for help to everybody :)